# How to convert a HTML Form Variable Passed to a PHP Script as a String?

Tags: php, html

So I have this HTML:

```
<form action="tickeroutput.php">Ticker Symbol: <input type="text" name="ticker" method="get"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
```

And then I want to use the data contained in ticker, however I have this in tickeroutput.php, and it doesn't seem to want to work:

```
    $ticker = $_GET("ticker");
```

Is this not the correct format to have $ticker as a string? I specifically need what the user inputs as a string variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use square brackets, not (). `$ticker = $_GET['ticker']` $_GET is an array.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I think you meant to write :

```
<form action="tickeroutput.php" method="get">Ticker Symbol: 
<input type="text" name="ticker"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
```

and to fix your problem you should replace `$ticker = $_GET("ticker");`
 with   `$ticker = $_GET["ticker"];` replace `()` with `[]`